# nginx mail proxy behind haproxy - get clients real ip address

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a mail proxy, for authentication and some other extras. But I need to use another proxy in front of nginx (like haproxy). All is ok, things working. But nginx can't retrieve clients real IP address.

In http module, i can forward it with x-forwarded-for header, and nginx's proxy_protocol. But in mail module, i can't do that. Mail module does not support proxy_protocol.

Is there any way, how can I pass clients real IP address to nginx?

My haproxy and nginx config like;

**haproxy.cfg:**

```
frontend IMAP
    bind 0.0.0.0:143 name IMAP tcp-ut 30s

    default_backend IMAP

backend IMAP
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect port 11143
    tcp-check expect string * OK

    server localhost 127.0.0.1:11143 send-proxy check
```

**nginx.conf**

```
mail {
    auth_http 127.0.0.1:333/auth;

    proxy on;
    imap_auth plain;
    server {
        listen 11143;
        protocol imap;
        auth_http_header proxyprotocol imap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This directive appeared in version 1.19.8.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol

```
server {
    server_name ImapServer;
    listen 11143 proxy_protocol;
    protocol imap;
}
```

Comment: Finally nginx support this. Thank you. It is worked.
PS: Some situations, you need to add `set_real_ip_from` in server block.